# Using mapply() For Column Row Comparison

Tags: r, performance, optimization, package

I am working with two different large data set and trying to make use of `mapply()` to get iterative functions working.

The goal is to take each data point column wise from *Data_1*, and compare it against both the data points in column of *Data_2*. So, *Data_1[1,1]* will be compared against *Data_2[1,1]* and *Data_2[2,1]* only. To be more clear, *data1* column in *Data_1* will only be compared against *dataA* elements in *Data_2*, thus no cross column comparison.

**Data_1: NxM**

```
  data1       data2       data3      data4
-0.710003   -0.714271   -0.709946   -0.713645
-0.710458   -0.715011   -0.710117   -0.714157
-0.71071    -0.714048   -0.710235   -0.713515
-0.710255   -0.713991   -0.709722   -0.713972
```

**Data_2: PxQ**

```
  dataA       dataB       dataC      dataD
-0.71097    -0.714059   -0.70928    -0.714059
-0.710343   -0.714576   -0.709338   -0.713644
```

I had earlier written a `for()` `while()` loop based algorithm, but the run time was too much as the original data is . Then, I moved to `apply()` based logic, but still had loops within function I was calling, so that didn't speed up the code. Based on [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894649/optimizing-apply-in-r), I am figuring out better way to do this with `mapply()`.

The part I am not able to visualize is the column to row comparison and how `mapply()` will navigate over it recursively. How can I use `mapply()` or `lapply()` to get this done efficiently?

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a nested *apply* family call:

- `mapply()` - outer: pairwise iteration between corresponding columns of *Data_1* and *Data_2*
- `sapply` - inner: vector iteration of each value in the *Data_1* column for element comparison

Below checks if each *Data_1* value is between the two values of each column of *Data_2*:

**Data**

```
txt = '  data1       data2       data3      data4
-0.710003   -0.714271   -0.709946   -0.713645
-0.710458   -0.715011   -0.710117   -0.714157
-0.71071    -0.714048   -0.710235   -0.713515
-0.710255   -0.713991   -0.709722   -0.713972'

Data_1 <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)

txt = ' dataA       dataB       dataC      dataD
-0.71097    -0.714059   -0.70928    -0.714059
-0.710343   -0.714576   -0.709338   -0.713644'

Data_2 <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)
```

**Code**

```
check_inbetween <- function(x,y){
  sapply(x, function(i) (i > y[1] & i < y[2]))
}

inbetween_matrix <- mapply(check_inbetween, Data_1, Data_2)

inbetween_matrix
#      data1 data2 data3 data4
# [1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, I guess even `sweep()` can be [used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959588/optimize-apply-while-in-r)

Comment: Possibly. I never used `sweep()`. And that implementation has an interesting nested sweep. My attempt seems to not recycle the function but only runs on first columns of datasets: `sweep(as.matrix(Data_1), 1, as.matrix(Data_2), FUN = function(x,y) (x > y[1] & x < y[2]), check.margin = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

That's one solution based on `data.table`, but if you are using data.frame or matrix, it should be easy to adapt. To reach what you want you must use one `lapply` over another `lapply`. The higher one iterates over the columns, which calls the other to iterate over the rows.

```
library(data.table)

# it gets all elements of column 'j' to do diff computation
get_column_diff <- function(dt_1, dt_2, j){

        get_point_diff <- function(i){
                # it should return a vector with all differences 
                # in comparison of the point (i,j)
                unlist(dt_1[i, ..j]) - unlist(dt_2[, ..j])
        }


        i_rows <- 1:nrow(dt_1)
        lapply(X=i_rows, FUN=get_point_diff)

}

j_cols <- 1:ncol(Data_1)
lapply(FUN=get_column_diff, dt_1=Data_1, dt_2=Data_2, X=j_cols)
```

The function returns a list of list, each element of the list is the column result and its element is a list with the row result.

About the speed gain, i can't say how fast it will be without benchmark comparison, but probably it will be faster the any loop.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelToledo. Your answer helps, but I need to dig more into how `unlist()` and `list()` work. Also, the line `j_cols <- 1:ncol(dt_1)` will lead to an error, right? as `dt_1` is being assigned `Data_1` after that?

Comment: my bad, i'll update it, inside the `ncol` must be `Data_1`. To organize your output, you have to think how you want it first, because your output will be something like `(n x n) x n`.