# Optimize Apply() While() in R

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, package

The data below is being used to perform comparative analysis. I wrote the code using `apply()` and `while()`, and even though it works as expected, I haven't been successful in optimizing it further. Current run time is more than couple of hours in larger data set.

Following is small example data set:

**data_1**

```
A B C D
2 1 3 2.5
```

**data_2**

```
P Q R S
3 2 4 5.5
```

**Data**

```
 A   B   C   D
1.0 0.5 1.3 1.5
1.5 1.2 5.5 3.5
1.1 0.5 1.3 1.5
1.5 1.2 5.5 3.5
1.5 1.2 5.5 3.5
1.1 0.5 1.3 1.5
1.5 1.2 5.5 3.5
1.0 0.5 1.3 1.5
```

**Code**

```
# Row counter 
rowLine <<- 0

# Set current column to first one
columnLine <<- 1

# Preserve column header and dimensions for final data
finalData <- Data

# Find recursively
findThreshold <- function () {

  if ( columnLine <= ncol(Data) ){

    # Initialize row navigation to zero
    rowLine  <<- 1

    # Navigate through rows
    while (rowLine <= nrow(Data)){

      # If outside threshold
      if ( (Data[rowLine, columnLine] < data_1[columnLine]) |
           (Data[rowLine, columnLine] > data_2[columnLine])){

        finalData[rowLine, columnLine] <<- 1

      } else {

        finalData[rowLine, columnLine] <<- 0

      }

      # Increment row counter
      rowLine <<- rowLine + 1

    }
  }

  # Increment column counter
  columnLine <<- columnLine + 1

}

# Apply
apply(Data, 2, function(x) findThreshold())
```

I also understand using `<<-` is a big no when it comes using it with `loops` and recursively analysis like `apply()`.

Please suggest how I can improve this logic further, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what your code is trying to do? I can run the function but I'm not sure what the output relates to.

Comment: @thelatemail - The output is stored in `finalData` as true false for each of the elements in `Data` by comparing it against lower threshold as `data_1` and higher threshold as `data_2`.

Comment: What about `finalData <- sapply(1:4, function(col) (Data[,col] < data_1[,col] |
Data[,col] > data_2[,col]))`

Comment: still error with rows 3 & 8

Comment: @HubertL - Thanks, it works. For replacing `TRUE` `FALSE` with `1` and `0`, I should add `if else` functionality in `function(col)`, or I can tell `sapply()` to use numeric values somehow?

Comment: just embed in `as.integer()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a simple `Map` exercise:

```
data.frame(Map(function(d,l,h) d < l | d > h, Data, data_1, data_2))
#     A     B    C     D
#1 TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#2 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#3 TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#4 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#5 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#6 TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#7 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#8 TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

Just wrap the logical comparison in `as.integer` if you want a 0/1 output instead:

```
data.frame(Map(function(d,l,h) as.integer(d < l | d > h), Data, data_1, data_2))
```

If your data are `matrix` objects to start with, you could use `sweep`:

```
sweep(Data, 2, data_1, FUN=`<`) | sweep(Data, 2, data_2, FUN=`>`)
#        A     B    C     D
#[1,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#[2,] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#[3,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#[4,] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#[5,] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#[6,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
#[7,] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
#[8,] TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail, your solution works too. I want to keep the output `finalData` matrix structure similar to `Data` including column names. With `Map` it's getting converted into a single row with logic values. This is the reason I did `finalData <- Data`, in order to copy matrix structure and then update it with logical values after comparison. Can you please suggest if this can be done using `Map` itself? I know my approach is not the best one.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil - `Map` just returns a list, which can be made into a `data.frame` the same size as `Data` by wrapping `data.frame(...)` around it - see my edit. The second line of code above including `as.integer` will be identical to your `finalData`

Comment: .@thelatemail - I did use `data.frame(....)` around `Map()` before testing the your code. It gives output as `1xN` instead of `MxN`.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil - is `Data` a `matrix`? I'm assuming it and `data_1/2` are `data.frame`s to start with. This is why a reproducible example is important.

Comment: .@thelatemail - Yes, it's a `matrix`. This is second time I messed up with `data.frame` vs `matrix` for reproducible example. `is.data.frame(Data) [1] FALSE`. Even my real data set is `matrix`.

Comment: .@thelatemail - It works, just figuring out how to use `as.integer()` with `sweep()`, as the output is non-numeric.

Comment: .@thelatemail - For converting to `integer`, I used `Data <- 1 * Data` expression after `sweep()`.