# Error Merging Two Columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to combine two columns, `Previous$Col1` and `Previous$Col3`, into one `data.frame`.

This is what I tried to do:

```
x<-data.frame(Previous$Col1)
y<-data.frame(Previous$Col3)
z<-merge(x,y)
```

And for some reason I got this `error` on the console:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 24.0 Gb
```

What's going wrong and what should I do to fix this?

How could a data frame with two columns with 80000ish rows take up 24 GB of memory?

Thanks!

Comment: The error says that you ran out of memory. It is pretty uncommon to "merge" two vectors. What is your desired output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)

Comment: Is this one column you are trying to merge?  Might work to append and then remove dupes....

Comment: But why did I run out of memory? I'm only trying to merge two 80000-row columns? How could that possibly be a 24 GB vector?

Comment: @RaiderNAYSHUN - That's something `Rstudio` is not good at, if you are using it. Check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894649/optimizing-apply-in-r#comment76839667_44895521).

Comment: We can't know why you ran out of memory without seeing your data. It looks like `merge` on two vectors is equivalent to `expand.grid`, as seen here: ` merge(1:3, 2:4)` and `expand.grid(1:3, 2:4)`. So you would end up with a Cartesian product of the vectors, which is 6.4 billion rows with two columns.

Comment: @Imo, my desired output is just a dataframe with the two columns combined

Comment: Can you just do `cbind(x,y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a full cartesian product, which has 80000*80000 rows and two columns, that is a total of 1.28e+10 elements (about 51GB if I am correct). What are you trying to accomplish with your merge?

```
> x<-data.frame(a= c("a","b"))
> y<-data.frame(b= c(1,2,3))
> z<-merge(x,y)
> x
  a
1 a
2 b
> y
  b
1 1
2 2
3 3
> z
  a b
1 a 1
2 b 1
3 a 2
4 b 2
5 a 3
6 b 3
```

You could do `data.frame(Col3 = Previous$Col3, Col1= Previous$Col1)` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `bind_cols` from the dplyr package or `cbind` from base R.

```
bind_cols(Previous$Col1,Previous$Col3)
```

or

```
cbind(Previous$Col1,Previous$Col3)
```

Additionally, since these columns come from the same original data.frame. `select()` from the dplyr package could be used:

```
select(Previous,Col1,Col3)
```