# how to bind datasets in r if the size of the vector is more than 300mb

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, data-science, data-cleaning

I am  working on a case study where I have to figure out some trends but the data is not in one dataset so I used **bind_row** function in R to bind all the datasets and get a dataset of the whole data but this error popped up.

all_trips_2013_2022<-
bind_rows(jun_to_dec_2013_trip_data,
jan_to_jun_2014_trip_data,
jul_2014_trip_data,
aug_to_sep_2014_trip_data)

Error in `bind_rows()`:
! cannot allocate vector of size 268.3 Mb.

Comment: Perhaps, you bind a subset of datasets, write to file, then do the other subset bind, and write to the same file with `append = TRUE` in a loop

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! You will get good help much faster if you provide sample data and sample code telling us what you tried. From the way this question is presented here, we have no idea what you data structure(s) look like so it is difficult to help. The recommendations appear to the right of the question box when asking a question - they are there to help you get good help - I suggest you edit your question to follow those guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing memory in R:

```
 > memory.limit()
[1] **current memory limit**
## To increase the storage capacity
> memory.limit(size=2800)
```

Also see: [Memory Allocation "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 75.1 Mb"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917532/memory-allocation-error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-75-1-mb)